# Nebular stepper NbStepper selectedIndex not working (possibly Angular Lifecycle related)

Tags: angular, nebular, stepper

I am not able to set the selectedIndex of a Nebular Stepper once it is created.
When I click on the button I see from the template that the variable is updated but the stepper doesn't change.

I thought the problem was that the stepper is inside a modal, so I built an MWE on StackBlitz ( [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-id5yop-qysdj9?file=src/app/home/config-dialog/config-dialog.component.ts) ) but here this works! Maybe the problem is get the content of the tabs from an http get JSON.

I tried using setTimeOut, zone.run(), ChangeDetectorRef etc.. but the tab never changes (event never triggered?). How can I programmatically set the visible tab?

Based on a condition I need to set the second or the third step, one workaround wold be to hide the second step when needed but in this case the problem is that nbStepperNext doesn't consider if a step is hidden ( https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/2372 )

here my package.json:

````
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points --tsconfig \"./src/tsconfig.app.json\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.1",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.9",
    "@nebular/auth": "^6.2.1",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "6.2.1",
    "@nebular/security": "^6.2.1",
    "@nebular/theme": "^6.2.1",
    "@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "^5.10.5",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^5.10.5",
    "@ngx-formly/schematics": "^5.10.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.27",
    "angular-datatables": "^9.0.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-labels": "^1.1.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.22",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.22",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.9",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.1.6",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.4",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to call the below functions to go back and forth bw indexes.

```
stepper.next()
stepper.previous()
```

To move to the desired Index.

Ex: In my case, i have to go to Index-2

```
for(let i=0; i< 2;i++) {
    this.stepper.next();
}
```